# VBA Evaluate Excel Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use "conditional" Large function in my code e.g. to use Large function for values where in the other column there is "Y".

I am using "Evaluate" function as I need only the results in the other part of the code.
However, this is not working - I understand that I need to work with **Formula2** because otherwise excel will add '@' to the function and it wont work. But still I dont know how to 'repair' evaluate function.

I am using R1C1 formula because later I want to use columns in the loop.

```
Sub Makro()
    'not working - there is '@' included
    Range("G3") = "=Large(if(c[-4]:c[-4]=""Y"", c[-3]),2)"
    'working
    Range("G4").Formula2 = "=Large(if(c[-4]:c[-4]=""Y"", c[-3]),2)"
    
    'not working
    Range("G5") = Evaluate("=Large(if(c[-4]:c[-4]=""Y"", c[-3]),2)")
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use A1 notation for `Evaluate`.

Comment: Btw, it would probably be more appropriate to use `.Formula2R1C1` instead of `.Formula2`.

Comment: Does this `ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("LARGE(IF(C:C=""Y"",D:D),2)")` work?

Comment: Yes,, ```Evaluate("=Large(if(C:C=""Y"", D:D),2)")``` is working for me. I understand that I need to work with funtion in that form (A1 instead of R1C1).
What is the best solution to re-write my function to adjust for the loop?
```Evaluate("=Large(if(C:C=""Y"", D:D),2)"), Evaluate("=Large(if(C:C=""Y"", E:E),2)"), Evaluate("=Large(if(C:C=""Y"", F:F),2)"), ...., Evaluate("=Large(if(C:C=""Y"", Z:Z),2)")```

Comment: You need to share on which range you mean to apply it: `G4:AC4` or `G4:G27` or...? In the same worksheet? Also, you may want to restrict the columns to e.g. `D5:DLastRow` to not severely slow down your workbook.

Comment: I will use 10x Evaluate function with different 2nd argument - so there should be ```D:D``` or ```E:E``` or ```Z:Z``` in ```Evaluate("=Large(if(C:C=""Y"", D:D),2)")```. WHta is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Evaluate in a Function

```vb
Sub EvaluateStuffTEST()
    Debug.Print EvaluateStuff("D", Sheet1) ' code name
    Debug.Print EvaluateStuff("E", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")) ' tab name
    Debug.Print EvaluateStuff("F") ' ActiveSheet
End Sub

Function EvaluateStuff( _
    ByVal ColumnString As String, _
    Optional ByVal SourceWorksheet As Worksheet = Nothing) _
As Variant
    If IsMissing(SourceWorksheet) Then Set SourceWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    EvaluateStuff = SourceWorksheet.Evaluate( _
        "=Large(if(C:C=""Y""," & ColumnString & ":" & ColumnString & "),2)")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - it is working as expected.
Quick question: is it possible to write a loop in EvaluateStuffTEST()? Let's say we have variable columns D, E, F, ...., ZZ?

Comment: It is possible (but it is kind of natural to have it this way). Then the result could be e.g. an array or a dictionary. Then again, you would need to loop it in another procedure. So you wouldn't gain much. It would make more sense if you would want to sum up those values. If you could explain the idea behind it maybe I could come up with a more accurate conclusion.